# Prove that a subgraph is a minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

Given:

```
G = (V,E)
T is an MST of G
G'=(V', E') ⊆ G
T' is an MST of G'
```

Prove:

```
(V',E∩T) is a subgraph of T'

Under what conditions is E∩T an MST of G'?
```

The edge-weights need not be distinct.

My approach:

By applying Kruskal's algorithm to edges in `E∩T`, one would join edges in ascending order of weight and simultaneously ensure that a join does not produce a cycle. This will produce *an* MST, but can a we show that this MST is a subgraph of `T'`?

Does this approach make sense? Since I do not use the fact that `T` is the MST of `G`, I have a hunch that I'm ignoring something important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observation: any graph with number of nodes `|V'|` and number of edges other than `|V'|-1` is not a tree, so one necessary condition is: `|E∩T| = |V'|-1`

Second observation: if `T'` is MST of `G'` then the sum of its edges is minimal among all other possible spanning trees of `G'`. which means that if `(V', E∩T)` is MST of `G'`, then the sum of its edges has to be equal to the sum of edges of `T'`

From observations above, the necessary and sufficient conditions for `(V', E∩T)` being MST of `G'` is:
1. `|E∩T| = |V'|-1`
2. `sumofweights((V', E∩T))=sumofweights(T')`

So, basically what you need to do is to count the number of edges in `E∩T` and compare with `|V'|-1`, and also calculate the sum of edge weights in `T'` and compare with the sum of edge weights in `E∩T`

However I got some suspicions about this line: `(V',E∩T) is a subgraph of T'`
Since `T'` also has `V'` nodes, any subgraph of `T'` other than `T'` itself, would not be a tree, and if it's not a tree, it can't be MST either. Probably it is `(V',E∩T) is a subgraph of G'` or `(V',E∩T) is a subgraph of T`, not `(V',E∩T) is a subgraph of T'`?